# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL after I upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to ubuntu 12.04.
Afterward, I try to compile android source.

But this is the error I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/triangleCM_intermediates/triangleCM] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
host Executable: triangleV2 (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/triangleV2_intermediates/triangleV2)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/triangleV2_intermediates/triangleV2] Error 1
true
```

Can you please tell me which library I need to install in order to resolve  '-lGL'?

Thank you.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/310314/ubuntu-11-04-recent-x11-update-broke-opengl

Answer (score 1):

A [search on packages.ubuntu.com for "libGL.so"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) shows which packages you may need to install.  Are you using nvidia drivers?  If so, it's possible that you need to install the restricted nvidia drivers to get the library back.